# Deploy lambdas in parallel with CodeBuild

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, aws-codebuild

I have a CodePipeline configured with my single GitHub repo to trigger build & deploy on any commit.

My repo contains dozens of individual lambda functions.

The pre_build step does a full clean & restore. Then in the build step, I have a long list of commands like this:

```yaml
- dotnet build -c Debug
- cd folder1
- dotnet lambda deploy-function --configuration Debug --region $Region --config-file aws-lambda-tools-test.json
- cd ../folder2
- dotnet lambda deploy-function --configuration Debug --region $Region --config-file aws-lambda-tools-test.json
- cd ../folder3
- dotnet lambda deploy-function --configuration Debug --region $Region --config-file aws-lambda-tools-test.json
```

My question is, is there any way for me to execute these deployments in parallel?